# How do I use the synchronized command correctly?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, runnable

I'm making a game to memorise katakana.  It plays like Whack-a-mole, and I have nine buttons that flash to show either true or false answers.

I have two textViews.  One displays romaji and the other katakana.  I need them to change in-sync.

I have one arrayList that contains romaji and another that contains the corresponding katakana.  Their indexes line up.
E.g. romaji = [a, i, u, e, o]
katakana = [ア, イ, ウ, エ, オ]

I'm using the following method to select which katakana and romaji to display.

```
public void QandA(){
    synchronized (this){
    pickFromArray = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, arraySize);
    textView29.setText(listromT.get(pickFromArray));
    hintView.setText(listT.get(pickFromArray));}
}
```

The textViews change in-synch if QandA is the only method that I run in handler (via a runnable).

However, if I run the runnables that make the buttons flash, the textViews will change out of sync.  E.g. it might show "a" with "オ".

My guess is that the textViews get out of synch because the computer is processing the nine buttons in between the commands for the textViews.  I was hoping the synchronize command would force the CPU to read the QandA method as an uninterrupted block, but they still change out of synch.

How do I use it correctly?  Or is there another command that I should be using instead?

Thanks

EDIT:

I have a SetQuestion runnable that I run recursively.

In onCreate:

```
 handler.postDelayed(SetQuestion, 0);
```

The SetQuestion runnable:

```
public Runnable SetQuestion = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    Qtimer++;
                    if (Qtimer%10==1){
                        QandA();
                    }
                    if (Qtimer%10==6){
                        QandA();
                    }
                    if (Qtimer>199){
                        Qtimer=110;
                    }
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);

                }
            });

        }
    };
```

I've also tried using TimerTasks for QandA and changing the buttons, but I get the same result.  The romaji and katakana change out of synch, although the buttons seem work fine (i.e. colours and text change in synch).

Comment: Can you share the other code which changes the text views apart from QandA method?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue another way.

I gave up on trying to set hintView in the QandA method.  Instead, I made the following method and put it in all the runnables for the buttons.

```
   public void katakana(){
            if (pickFromArray ==0){
                hintView.setText("ア");
            }
            if (pickFromArray ==1){
                hintView.setText("イ");
            }
            if (pickFromArray ==2){
                hintView.setText("ウ");
            }
            if (pickFromArray ==3){
                hintView.setText("エ");
            }
            if (pickFromArray ==4){
                hintView.setText("オ");
            }
    }
```